# jQuery animation: How to move a value from the left to the right and back?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-animate

I would like to move a value in a class from the left to the right and back after clicking on any star. Below picture may help to imaging what I am trying to achieve. In this case I want the "4.0" move to the right and back after I click on a star. (The 4.0 is a generated value from Rails.)

[image]

I am trying to apply the following code from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1). It does work in the example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHLuE/), but it doesn't work in my code. Everything else works just fine.

What am I missing here?
Many thanks.

**HTML**

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#/routes/1">Route 1</a>
        <div id="Route1" class="rate_widget">
        <div class="star_1 ratings_stars <%= Score.average('score', :conditions => 'route_id = 1') >= 1 ? "ratings_vote" : "" %>" data-score="1"></div>
        <div class="star_2 ratings_stars <%= Score.average('score', :conditions => 'route_id = 1') >= 2 ? "ratings_vote" : "" %>" data-score="2"></div>
        <div class="star_3 ratings_stars <%= Score.average('score', :conditions => 'route_id = 1') >= 3 ? "ratings_vote" : "" %>" data-score="3"></div>
        <div class="star_4 ratings_stars <%= Score.average('score', :conditions => 'route_id = 1') >= 4 ? "ratings_vote" : "" %>" data-score="4"></div>
        <div class="star_5 ratings_stars <%= Score.average('score', :conditions => 'route_id = 1') == 5 ? "ratings_vote" : "" %>" data-score="5"></div>
        </div>  
        <div class="total_votes"><%= "%0.1f" %  Score.average('score', :conditions => 'route_id = 1') %></div>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.ratings_stars 
    {
    background: url('star_empty.png') no-repeat;
    float:      left;
    height:     28px;
    padding:    2px;
    width:      32px;
    }

.total_votes 
    {
    background: yellow;
    top: -10px;
    margin: 12px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 5px;
    position: relative;  
    width: 170px;
    height: 17px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: red;
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
// This records the vote
        $('.ratings_stars').on('click', function() {
        var score=$(this).attr("data-score");
        var route_id=$(this).parent().attr("id").replace('Route', '');  


// This moves the score to the right
      $('.ratings_stars').click(function() {
        $('.total_votes').animate({left:'50px'}, 500)
          $('.total_votes').animate({left:'0px'}, 500);
      });

            $.post(
                '/scores',  // this sends the voting data to the page '/scores'
                {
            "score[score]": score,
            "score[route_id]": route_id
        },
                function() { 
            alert('Thank you for your vote.');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to animate `text-indent` property to move text inside its container `<div class="total_votes">`.

Following code will do the rest:

```
$("div.ratings_stars").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parents("li").find("div.total_votes")
                 .animate({'text-indent': '150px'})
                 .delay(100)
                 .animate({'text-indent':'0px'});
    });
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/7sRma/) is link to working code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/7sRma/).